# How to conditionally assign a local variable reference to a another variable in c#?

Tags: c#, reference

What I want to do would look something like this in c/c++:

```
bool MyFunc(eMyType t)
{
  sMyStruct* s=(t==TypeX) ? &VarMyStructX : &VarMyStructY;

  if (s->dataneeded>0) 
    return true;

  return false;
}
```

But in C# none of the assignments seem to work:

```
public bool MyFunct(in eMyType t)
{
  // This causes: Cannot initialize a by-reference variable with a value
  ref sMyStruct s=(t==eMyType.TypeX) ? ref VarMyStructX : ref VarMyStructY;
  // This causes: A ref or out argument must be an assignable variable
  ref sMyStruct s=ref ((t==eMyType.TypeX) ? VarMyStructX : VarMyStructY);
  // This causes: You can only take the address of an unfixed expression inside of a fixed statement initializer
  sMyStruct* s=(t==TypeX) ? &VarMyStructX : &VarMyStructY;

  if (s.dataneeded > 0)
    return true;

  return false;
}
```

How do I do it in C#?

I basically don't want to make a copy of the structure to the other structure because it is not needed. I just want to reference the correct variable.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is possible, just not possible with the ternary operator `?:`.  Use regular IF..ELSE statements.

This is a sample I created quickly at ideone.com:

```cs
using System;

public struct Point
{
    public int X;
    public int Y;
}

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Func<Point, string> dp = x => $"({x.X}, {x.Y})";
        Point p0 = new Point();
        Point p1 = new Point() { X = 1, Y = 2 };
        Point p2 = new Point() { X = 3, Y = 4 };
        string decider = null;
        do
        {
            decider = Console.ReadLine();
            ref Point p = ref p0;
            if (decider == "1")
            {
                p = ref p1;
            }
            else
            {
                p = ref p2;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(dp(p));
        } while (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(decider));
    }
}
```

It is perfectly possible to reassign the ref variable, you just have to do it the long-winded way.

Comment: FWIW: ref sMyStruct s=ref (t==eMyType.TypeX) ? ref VarMyStructX : ref VarMyStructY;